# How do i install postgis on ubuntu server?

Tags: postgresql

My pc showing i have two versions of Postgres installed.

```
postgres=# \c viserver
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4), server 11.7 (Ubuntu 11.7-0ubuntu0.19.10.1))
```

I installed PostGIS using `sudo apt-get install postgis` but it installed PostGIS in Postgres 12.
 But I want to install it in Postgres 11. cause my server version using postgres 11.
because `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` on a database giving error

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

the error you see means that some packages are not installed.

To have *postgis.control* please check and install

```
postgresql-11-postgis-X.Y (e.g. X.Y = 2.5)
```

and

```
postgresql-11-postgis-X.Y-scripts
```

Regards,

Mohamad

Answer (score 1):

It helped what S. Mohamad explained. But I want to share the exact answer.

## Steps to resolve the error:

- Try to run `sudo apt install postgresql-11-postgis`. This will install but provide suggestion what to install like below.
  [image]
- You can see the 2 versions of postgis I installed the latest version by `sudo apt install postgresql-11-postgis-3`
- After installing required package you can run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` in postgres and it will show you following:
  [image]

Yay!! No errors.